# How to express a "read only record" type in TypeScript that is covariant with compatible interfaces?

Tags: typescript, covariance, typescript-generics

I need to define a method that serializes objects for storage, but the semantics of it require that it can only work with objects whose fields keys are of string type (because they must match the column's names, so they cannot be numbers).

Using a `Record<string, unknown>` type won't work for this serializer input, because I am supplying it objects that have specific fields defined (like `interface Foo {foo: number, bar: string}` and these are not assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`).

Same thing why we cannot do safely assign a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>` if `List` is mutable, but we can if they are immutable .

So I need to either specify that a generic type parameter's `keyof T` is a subset of `string` or have a `ReadOnlyRecord<string, unknown>` that is covariant with any interface that has string keys.

Suggestions?

Comment: the only thing I am not sure about your question is where `readonly` comes into play. I hope the answer is exactly what you've been looking for, but if not could you please supply a link to playground with a sample of the desired result?

Comment: yeah, it's not straightforward what I meant, I wasn't addressing the `readonly` property but rather immutable as in a frozen map/collection that can be safely assigned to maps/collections of upper bound generic types.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my inquiry too :) I meant the same as you, and the `readonly` keyword is not used as a modifier here. Seems like you are able to apply the solution to your use case, but if you don't mind satisfying my curiosity - can you post later a playground link of how everything combined looks like?

Comment: @OlegValter actually, I might have rushed saying that I got what I wanted... it is a little bit more convoluted (involving another layer of generic classes), but I will try to update the final result :)

Comment: no worries :) Is there anything about the task you could use help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to take variance into account here. The reason why `Record<string, unknown>` fails is simply due to the utility requiring its type parameter to have an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). For the same reason, the method cannot expect to get a type assignable to `{ [x:string]: unknown }` as its only parameter.

In any case, I do not think you will be able to do that without generic type parameters. Then you simply need to check if a string-only keyed type like `{ [P in Extract<keyof T, string> : any }` is assignable to the passed-in type (the other way around will obviously always pass as your interfaces are subtypes of the former).

Note that `X extends T ? T : never` in the parameter is needed for the compiler to be able to infer `T` from usage while still maintaining the constraint. The only caveat is that you will not be able to catch `symbol` properties (but will be if their type is `unique symbol`):

```ts
{
    class Bar {
        public baz<T extends object>(serializable: { [P in Extract<keyof T,string>] : any } extends T ? T : never) { return JSON.stringify(serializable); }
    }

    const foo: Foo = { foo: 42, bar: "answer" };

    const nope = { [1]: true };

    const symb = { [Symbol("ok")]: 24 };

    const US: unique symbol = Symbol("unique");

    const usymb = { [US]: Infinity };

    const bar = new Bar();
    bar.baz(foo); //OK
    bar.baz(nope); //Argument of type '{ 1: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
    bar.baz(symb); //OK? Inferred as `{ [x: string]: number; }`
    bar.baz(usymb); //Argument of type '{ [US]: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=34&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN40wLmRAFcBbAI2gBply4pCBnMKUAcwF8AoL7L5AcgQAbOI0bIAQvRz9B8gA7Fyw4AlpwAXgApG0YHFWa4KiPgBKEBOigATADzNWINjWIgA1iHQB3EAD4AShxkKAgwYigQZAApAGUAeQA5ADondmAYAE9dfUNgY1NAgG5kbnluOQFrEGZkPHRCDCwAXhCGwgAWACYaOgZkACI4Wp9oQbLinnkauv7kNpAIHyl6bRKqjSgUuh0GkuQAekOASRBbCAAPZEZgNhA4CLDkYAlSV9uXF%20iwLIUUADkzQBKS4lT4M1E4lWUFk8kUylU6l29gAKsgrpBzhJ0OQAFZWMD%20XKsfKFYRmEIAbQACt9kABRS4sRBgeweCBZdAwZCoqjpFz%20AC6yEIIyyZQxzIg2N5yAA-HLCEsAG7QYLYULhSLReLJNIsDLZEkGIwmCkHcqCSozdC1MD1AhoTALdpOnp9eiEYajcaTaaCWYO7z-V2aqkARiFhBYxBQHCmmyDNyyFDDyCpcVT5HQwm0g3QHkGgWjyG6nX9SbtdQAqnFCO5gABHOMpii511Z9t5waNlsQYuJ2325DERjZ9NUuuls4wUDAX6V4dzGSLZYw9ZTeT9HZabT7UrHBIAaU2O922hDEAOxwAglA2GQZQ7uchfqGAZqI4Qc7mICNSg4AEXgkbwHTEW57nNFAwCwBR6DgUhwmgZBX3fQFVWgAEz3oXcdHHCgb0OE9FVnaAwlsZAxGQAADcNLiYQ0XFLEgKGgQCaJw7YLzHbMiPvR8kPAVCeXQ5BPwzadlTISgoEA4DXiIdBwPEO4HlMN84IQpDIFhNC-gwiA1SgbCOCAA)

Comment: The `Extract` generic type is the piece of the puzzle that I was missing, I think I would be able to adapt this to my use case! Thank you very much!

Comment: @fortran - glad it works for your use case! Sometimes I wish we could express something like `{ [ only strings but not an index signature ] : any }` without shenanigans with generics. Maybe there is an issue / proposal I am missing, if I dig up something, will update the answer with the info.